# What happens with Rails indentation in outputted HTML?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, indentation

I'm writing code for a Rails view in TextMate (using the 2-space indentation standard). Whenever I view the output of my webpages (View Source), the HTML brackets always seem weirdly indented. For example, my application.html.erb looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Rainleader</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :all %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="outer">
        <div class="contentwidth main">
            <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
        </div>

        <%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

And the partial it's rendering (_header.html.erb) looks like this:

```
<div class="logo">
    <h1><a href="index.html">minimal.</a></h1>
</div><!-- end logo -->
```

But, an excerpt of the outputted HTML has misplaced (mis-indented) brackets (see my notes in the code below):

```
<body>
    <div id="outer">

        <div class="contentwidth main">
                        <div class="logo"> <<<Why is this so far to the right?
    <h1><a href="index.html">minimal.</a></h1>   <<<Why is this so far to the left?
</div><!-- end logo -->
```

What's going on here? If my call to the _header.html.erb partial in application.html.erb is indented four spaces, do I need to indent the code in the partial by at least that same amount to have it nest properly?

Comment: why do you care about the indentation of the output html?

Comment: Good question, I just like to have clean code. Call me weird, but it bugs me.

Comment: Indentation matters for me when rendering is in a `<pre>` tag.

Comment: For my purposes I was able to address the indentation in `<pre>` with `white-space: pre-line;`. This doesn't help the HTML (but I'm not concerned about that as we compress everything).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line of the partial that is rendered is indented as `<%= render 'layouts/header' %>` in application.html.erb. But all other lines of code are not indented further, just left-aligned as they are in your partial. It bugged me too, which is part of why I started using haml.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that. Thanks :)

Comment: So this suggests the line `<%= render 'layouts/header' %>` should NOT  be indented.

Comment: I found a similar issue in haml, except it indents all lines except the first